# how to identify the modification in a method inside a java file?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, eclipse-jdt

I have created  a plugin  where i am in a need of finding the changes inside the method. I have used                  JavaCore.addElementChangedListener  to listen to the changes happening in the java file. but i cant get the changes inside the method. I want to get the changes inside the method .I have gone through the [How to capture changes inside methods in an Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761220/how-to-capture-changes-inside-methods-in-an-eclipse-plugin) but i am not able to get the subtrees and changes fileds . Actually am not able to get the actual concept . can you please help me to get the changes in the method?

Comment: What, specifically, are "the changes" that you want to find?  It might be clear to you, but it isn't clear to us.  Do you mean modifications to local fields?  To parts of your data model?  To something else?

Comment: if the user changes some logic inside the method i need the method name where the changes happened.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle: is ther is any way to get the method name ? am very much in need of it now . please help me with this

Comment: What changes do you mean? Field-Values or Sourcecode?

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do makes much sense.  In order to run an application, the source code is compiled down to bytecode - and those specific instructions are executed.  If the source files *used to* be different, there's no way that the running program can know that.  It just executes exactly the instructions that are in the (latest) version of the code.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want to achieve, but you might want to look into our Fluorite project (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fluorite/). It gives you all the fine-grained "text" changes (not the structural changes) and their locations (character offsets) in the file. You could use the tool directly or at least read/fork the source code and do something similar for your own purposes.

Comment: changes in the sense source code.. i have created a plugin which will generate file with a selected method content and if the user modifies the source code it must automatically reflected in the generated file.. for that i need the class name and method name of the changed event. by using javaCore.addElementChangedListener i can get the class name but how i can get the method name where the source code is modified. when the user saves the changes i need to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally some how I found the solution to identify the changes happening inside the method but it gives simultaneously . I store it in a hash map as specified in the [How to capture changes inside methods in an Eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761220/how-to-capture-changes-inside-methods-in-an-eclipse-plugin) answer and by using IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE we can get the collection of changes happened up to the user saves the file.

```
public void elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent event) {
     IJavaElementDelta delta= event.getDelta();
        if (delta != null) {               
            delta.getCompilationUnitAST().accept(new ASTVisitor() {

             @Override
             public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
                 String name = ( (TypeDeclaration) node.getParent()).getName()
                     .getFullyQualifiedName() + "." + node.getName().getFullyQualifiedName();

                 boolean changedmethodvalue = false;

                 if (subtrees.containsKey(name)){

                    changedmethodvalue = !node.subtreeMatch(new ASTMatcher(),subtrees.get(Name));

                     if(changedmethodvalue){

                      System.out.println("method  changed"+Name+":"+changedmethodvalue);

                      /**
                       * Store the changed method inside the hash map for future reflection.
                       */

                      changed.put(Name, (IMethod) node.resolveBinding().getJavaElement());

                      /**
                       * setting up the hash map value each time changes happened.
                       * 
                       */
                      ModificationStore.setChanged(changed);



                      }
                 }
                 else{

                     // No earlier entry found, definitely changed
                     methodHasChanged = true;
                     System.out.println("A new method is added");

                 }

             }
                      /**
                     * updating the subtree structure 
                     */
                       subtrees.put(mName, node);

                       return true;
                   }
               });

       }
   }
}
```

When the user invokes save option we can get the collection of method name and its location from the hash map

```
 public class InvokeSynchronizer  implements IResourceDeltaVisitor{

private static HashMap<String, IMethod> methodtoinvoke = new HashMap<String, IMethod>();

public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) {

       IResource res = delta.getResource();
        switch (delta.getKind()) {

          case IResourceDelta.ADDED:
              System.out.println("ADDED: ");
          break;
        case IResourceDelta.CHANGED:
          /**
               * methodtoinvoke is a hash map values got from the modification store class.
               */
              methodtoinvoke=ModificationStore.getChanged();

               Iterator it = methodtoinvoke.entrySet().iterator();
              while (it.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                //  System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
                  IMethod methods=(IMethod) pairs.getValue();

                  //IResource resource=(IResource) methods;

                  System.out.println("I resource value"+res);

                  System.out.println("\nlocation of the method:"+methods.getParent().getResource().toString());
                  System.out.println("\n\nmethod name ::"+methods.getElementName());

                  it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
              }}
       return true; 
    }
```

}